# Serve Googlebot varnish cached

Tags: nginx, varnish, googlebot

I'm currently running Nginx with php5-fpm and I would like to instroduce varnish to my server setup but I only want varnish to serve cached pages to Googlebot and Bingbot, and anyone else pass cache.

What is the best way to do this? run varnish as a frontend or run nginx as a frontend and send request to varnish? Also I would require the actual code please.

Any comments would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the user agent you could identify the bots and let varnish cache the response. see the following varnish library for more info https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect

But I wonder why you want to put varnish in there in the first place, especially to only handle the bots. why not let nginx handle the caching (if that is even a practical option).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Marcel's answer, you could just use NGINX to handle caching of responses for Bots only (no need for Varnish):

```
# Map any user agent not containing the word "bot"
map $http_user_agent $isNotBot {
  ~*bot    "";
  default  "IAmNotARobot";
}

# Where to store cached files (adjust to your liking)
proxy_cache_path /path/to/bot_cache
  levels=1:2
  keys_zone=bot_cache:10m
  max_size=1g
  inactive=30m
  use_temp_path=off;

server {
  ...
  location / {
    ...
    # Which cache to use
    fastcgi_cache bot_cache;

    # key to use for the cached copies (adjust to your needs)
    fastcgi_cache_key $host:$server_port:$request_uri;

    # Bypass the cache for humans
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $isNotBot;

    # Don't store/cache copies of requests from humans
    fastcgi_no_cache     $isNotBot;

    # Uses stale cached responses for various upstream errors
    # (ignored for humans)
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500;

    # Disable getting gzipped files from back end
    # (only cache un-gzipped responses)
    fastcgi_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

    # upstream location
    fastcgi_pass http://upstream;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

replace `fastcgi_` with `proxy_`, `scgi_` or `uwsgi_` depending on which proxy module you are using.